# How to detect "original" URL request in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a question that I couldn't find an answer to so far. Basically, I already know how to check the redirect URL:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        println(webView.request?.URL.absoluteURL)
        if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked){
            if (webView.request?.URL.path == "/contact-us") {
                self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 4
            }
            return false
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

The problem I have now is that I implemented this code:

```
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath
    var baseUrl  = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("\(path)")
    webView.loadHTMLString(finalHtml, baseURL: baseUrl)
```

Therefore, I am not getting the URL that is in the hyperlink. I believe this is because I changed the baseURL. Now, how should I get the "original" url in the  tags?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! =D

**EDIT** To make myself clearer, here is the output when I print out the request URL:
`Optional(file:///Users/<My folder name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/681E8ACA-B0EB-48B0-9FA4-FC89D3EE2044/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8EB249C9-6362-4A92-B83F-8CDB5C181AAE/<appname>.app/)`

Also, if the `baseUrl` was `nil`, I get "about:blank".

Answer (score 0):

i'm not 100% sure of what youre asking but it seems like a simple string replacement.

```
NSString *path = webView.request?.URL.path;
NSString *cmp  = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:webView.request.baseURL
                                 withString:@""];
if (cmp == "/contact-us") {

}
```

actually, just checking docs it seems you might just want the last path component

```
if (webView.request.URL.lastPathComponent == "contact-us") {

}
```

Comment: Looks promising. I will give it a try =D

Comment: Take a look at my Edit. My last path component is my <appname>.app

Comment: what do you get in webView.request.URL.absolutePath, webView.request.URL.absoluteString

Comment: same thing as above. Noting with the actual path